# How can I map from one object's properties to another's constructor parameters?

Tags: automapper, automapper-3

Imagine classes like this:

```
class Source
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

class Destination
{
    public Destination(string name, int code)
    {}
}
```

I want to configure a mapping from `Source` to `Destination`. **I want AutoMapper to automatically match `Source.Name` to `Destination`'s `name` constructor parameter** since they have the same name (excluding naming conventions) and type. However, the second constructor parameter will need to be custom-mapped.

The best I could find so far is to just manually do all of the mappping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ConstructUsing(source => new Destination(source.Name, /*Custom map for "code" property*/));
```

However, by doing this, I lose the maintainability improvements that convention-based mapping offers.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer the question, but I ended up concluding that it was easier to just not use AutoMapper for scenarios like this. It's trivial to write a method that receives one object and creates an instance of another without using AutoMapper:

```
Destination Map(Source source)
{
    return new Destination(source.Name, source.Code);
}
```